# What the function of zener diode on this picture

Tags: mosfet, over-voltage-protection

[image]

I am confuse,  why we need clamping with zener diode because it doesnt matter when vgs goee below zero, cmiiw

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't matter if Vgs goes (far) below 0?

Answer (score 1):

They are protection of the gate. Yes it does not matter if Vgs goes below zero, but it matters if Vgs goes beyond the maximum rating of the mosfet, either in positive or negative.

That is why there are 2 zener diode connected in opposing direction.

---

EDIT

I implied that this circuit may have a positive or negative drive for the gate, which is not clear on the question. If there is supposed to be only positive drive on the gate, only a single Zener would be necessary as protection.

Comment: I think the point is, why not just use the single Zener diode, which protects against negative voltages even sooner, at -0.65V? The MOSFET is cut off at any negative gate voltage, so why do we care about letting it go more negative than that?

Comment: I did not understood the question this way. Given the circuit we do not know if the mos gate can be driven with negative voltage, I assumed so given there are 2 zener.

Comment: The symbol used is that of an enhancement-mode N-channel MOSFET, the most common type. Clearly the only *useful* range of gate voltages will be positive.

Comment: There are use case where you want to drive both on positive and negative, for instance an op-amp driven dual side current regulation where you have to N-Mos in series where you have both gate tied together.

Comment: Now you're talking about a completely different circuit from the one the OP is asking about.

Comment: If the MOSFET is being driven by an op-amp with +/-15 volt rails then either 2 zeners or a TVS is needed, however this diagram does not define the range of Vin. When in doubt at least 1 zener diode is needed.